# Java Distributing event to classes

Tags: java, android, drupal, drupal-7

I am developing an android app for invoice management. Every invoice is linked to a client. And if an invoice becomes overdue a notification is generated.

Now What I wanted is when a client is deleted I want to delete all his/her invoices, payments and notifications.

For that I created a hook pattern like drupal (As I was previously a drupal developer). Following code tells how this patter works.

How hooks are called :

```
public void callClientDeletedHooks(ClientNew client) {
        final ArrayList<Object> frArr = HookClasses.getClasses();

        if (frArr != null && !frArr.isEmpty()) {
            for (Object frg : frArr) {
                try {
                    if (frg instanceof Hooks.ClientDeletedHook) {
                        Hooks.ClientDeletedHook hooks = (Hooks.ClientDeletedHook) frg;
                        hooks.clientDeleted(client, getActivity());
                    }
                } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**callClientDeletedHooks is called right after a client is deleted and it gets the object of client being deleted. Finally this object is distributed to every class that implement that hook.**

**Hook interfaces :**

```
public interface Hooks {

    public interface ClientDeletedHook {
        public void clientDeleted(ClientNew client_new, Context ctx);
    }

    // Place for other hooks
}
```

**How I am registering the classed that implement the hook**

```
public class HookClasses {

    public static ArrayList<Object> getClasses() {
        ArrayList<Object> fArr = new ArrayList<Object>();

        fArr.add(new NotificationListFragment());
        fArr.add(new BaseInvoicesListFragment());
        fArr.add(new ReturnListFragment());
        fArr.add(new PaymentListFragment());

        return fArr;
    }

}
```

**How I am implementing the hook in class. An Example.**

```
public class NotificationListFragment extends BaseFragment implements
        Hooks.ClientDeletedHook {

    // This hook is called when client deleted

    @Override
    public void clientDeleted(ClientNew client_new, Context ctx) {
        NotificationUtil _iu = NotificationUtil.getInstance(ctx);
        try {
             // Here I am deleting all notification for a client
            _iu.delete_row_from_table("notification", "client_id", ""
                    + client_new.getClient_id());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Now my question is is it the right way to distribute an event like client being deleted to many classes ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about drupal pattern but for this type of problems you can take the **Observer Pattern** in Java. That is the best pattern for that type of problems and you are very near to that pattern.